# The modules in my package have got "self" attributes that bypass __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, installation, package

I've built a package in Python 3. The problem is that when I import the package, every module has got those functions specified in *__init__.py* AND an attribute with the same name as the module (say package.package) that has got all the functions in the actual package.

I've tried to change my *__init__.py* files but I guess I'm not properly understanding how it works.
My package looks like that:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    package.py (same name used here)
    _someprivatestuff.py
    io/
        __init__.py
        io.py
    vis/
        __init__.py
        vis.py
```

The fist *__init__.py* contains the following imports:

```
from .package import exception1
from .package import exception2
from .package import class1
from .package import class2
from .package import class3
```

Exceptions and classes are in package.py.

Now, if I import the module, I've got access to every other functions in package.py and the modules imported in this python files:

```py
import package

package.class1 # this should output 'package.class1'
>>> <class 'package.package.class1'>
package.package.someprivateclass # package.package is somehow accesible
>>> <class 'package.package.someprivateclass'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`package.package` is a module, it has functions in it, so you can access them as `package.package.someprivateclass`.  Just because you've imported some names from `.package` into `__init__.py` doesn't mean that the names you haven't imported will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that makes sense. So would it be a good practice to rename _package.py_ to something like _core.py_ or is it ok the way it is? (Obviously 'package' isn't the real name of the package).

Comment: `package.package` is odd, I would change it.